# 15 days Schengen visa, what are technicalities for travelling to Turkey also on the same document?

Tags: visas, turkey

I have a 15 day Schengen visa 25 November to 15 December) my port of entry is Italy. After spending 2 weeks in Italy I will be going to Turkey for a week. My doubts are

- as I have a multiple entry visa and an Indian passport Based on that I will be getting Turkish visa
- even if I have 2 days of my valid Schengen visa remaining. On arrival can I get a 10 plus days visa stay in Turkey?

Comment: Turkey does not belong to [Schengen Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area). Schengen visa and Turkish visa are two independent documents.

Comment: @mouviciel There are exemptions for holders of Schengen visas, see http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa

Comment: I hold an Indian passport. And checked again, I have a multiple entry visa. M in turkey on 8the December and schengan visa expires on 10. Can I get a visa on arrival?

Comment: @Zeba: Please edit ammendments into your original question rather than solely in a comment. You cannot expect every person who might know the answer to dredge through comments to see if any of them alter the question.

Comment: Done. Thanks. Turkish embassy website doesn't address these small technicalities and its off for a long weekend since thurs

Answer (score 3):

Visa requirements will depend on your citizenship. You can find the specifics on [the website of the Turkish Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa). If your passport allows you to enter Turkey visa free or get a visa-on-arrival anyway, the Schengen visa won't make a difference.

However, if you would normally need a regular visa and hoped to get a Turkish e-visa/sticker on arrival on the basis of your Schengen visa, I don't think it will work. With a single entry visa, once you have an exit stamp from a Schengen country, you cannot enter the area again so I doubt it would qualify as a “*valid*  Schengen visa” for the Turkish authorities.

A related question has been asked before regarding Bulgaria ([Duration of Schengen visa while travelling to non Schengen areas which allow Schengen visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21236/duration-of-schengen-visa-while-travelling-to-non-schengen-areas-which-allow-sch?lq=1)) but unfortunately nobody has been able to provide definitive information.